# Configuring AWS keys for a Linux user using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am trying to find an Ansible module that would allow me to set up the Secret and Access Keys for a certain user on a target machine. The command line equivalent of this would be:-

```
11:14:26 root@ov90-NAT ~ [33] {e=255}
# aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: something
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: something
Default region name [None]: us-east-1
Default output format [None]: json
```

I'm fairly new to both Ansible and AWS so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass credentials to Ansible  modules, Ansible  has dedicated [section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_aws.html#authentication) on how to do it using **environment variables** or `vars_file`.

You can also explicitly set them using [set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/set.html) command, e.g.:

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id default_access_key
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key default_secret_key
aws configure set default.region us-west-2
```

You can also have your Ansible  recipe to create the config files  `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`. Their format is shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html).